# Python Numpy: reshape is deprecated

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to reshape a vector into an array

```
myArray = np.reshape(myVector,[nCol,nRow])
```

but I get a depreciation warning:

```
FutureWarning: reshape is deprecated and will raise in a subsequent release. Please use .values.reshape(...) instead
  return reshape(newshape, order=order)
```

When I use

```
myArray = np.values.reshape(myVector,[nCol,nRow])
```

I get an error

```
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'values'
```

Please can someone explain what's going on and what I should be doing? Many thanks

Comment: That is not a numpy warning.  Is `myVector` a Pandas object?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Yes, myVector is one column from a larger dataframe. Sorry I overlooked that

Comment: You need to access the numpy array object before reshape it then `np.reshape(myVector.values, (nCol,nRow))`

Comment: Or the method form: `myVector.values.reshape(...)`

Answer (score 4):

calling np.reshape(whatever args) is no longer the preferred way to call the function. instead, use this: 
    `myArray = myVector.values.reshape([nCol,nRow])`

Comment: irrelevant to the question just pointing out, this is not supported by numba

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problems using this:

```
train_set_X = train_df["STRAIGHT_DIST"]
train_set_X_np = np.array(train_set_X)
train_set_X_np = train_set_X_np.reshape([train_set_X.shape[0], 1])
```

In your specific case, you should use this:

```
myVector_np = np.array(myVector)
myVector_np = myVector_np.reshape([myVector.shape[0], 1])
```